# Masonry - AJAX Appended tiles not displayed

Tags: ajax, layout, masonry

I've made quite some researche but haven't found a solution at my problem.
I'm building a masonry grid with php that display's great.

The problem comes when I whant to load more images with AJAX. The tiles are added but the layout is not refreshed correctly !

Here is my init function :

```
function initNewsMasonry()
{
  oNewsGrid = document.querySelector('.grid');
  oNewsMsnry = new Masonry( oNewsGrid, {
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    percentPosition: true
  });
}
```

I followed the tutorial https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nhekz for vanilla JS. here is the code for inserting tiles :

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
  {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    if(myObj.length > 0)
    {
      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
      var elems = [];
      for(iIndex=0; iIndex<myObj.length; iIndex++)
      {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.className = myObj[iIndex]["class"];
        element.innerHTML = myObj[iIndex]["innerHTML"];

        fragment.appendChild(element);
        elems.push(element);
      }
      oNewsGrid.appendChild(fragment);
      oNewsMsnry.appended(elems);

      // doesn't change the result with reloadItems()
      oNewsMsnry.reloadItems();
      oNewsMsnry.layout();
    }
  }
};
```

And this is the CSS :

```
.grid {
  max-width: 2000px;
}

/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item,
.grid-sizer {
  width:33.2%;
}

img,
video {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.grid-item .newsTxt {
  opacity: 0;
  height:94%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3%;
  right: 3%;
  top: 3%;
  color: #000000;
  background: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

here is the html code generated - after page load :

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 659.344px;">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/125/500x500/refe_03.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-125" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">14.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 0</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 33.1823%; top: 0px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/126/500x500/proj_07.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-126" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">13.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 1</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 66.3646%; top: 0px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/127/500x500/refe_06.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-127" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">12.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 2</font></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here after 1st AJAX load (3 tiles each load for example):

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 659.344px;">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/125/500x500/refe_03.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-125" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">14.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 0</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 33.1823%; top: 0px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/126/500x500/proj_07.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-126" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">13.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 1</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 66.3646%; top: 0px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/127/500x500/refe_06.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-127" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">12.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 2</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 659px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/128/500x500/photo_youtube.jpg">
    <div id="newsTxt-128" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">11.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 3</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 659px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/129/500x500/proj_07.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-129" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">10.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 4</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 659px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/130/500x500/refe_03.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-130" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">09.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 5</font></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that the 3 (or any number) new tiles are all positioned at 0% and at the same height.

But at the 2nd AJAX load :

```
<div class="grid" style="position: relative; height: 659.344px;">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  //////
  ///////// same divs as initial page load /////////
  //////
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 659px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/128/500x500/photo_youtube.jpg">
    <div id="newsTxt-128" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">11.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 3</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 33.1823%; top: 659px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/129/500x500/proj_07.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-129" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">10.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 4</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 66.3646%; top: 659px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/130/500x500/refe_03.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-130" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">09.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 5</font></div>
  </div>
    <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 1318px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/131/500x500/proj_06.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-131" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">08.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 6</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 1318px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/133/500x500/photo_youtube.jpg">
    <div id="newsTxt-133" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">07.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 7</font></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 1318px;">
    <img src="./Images/News/136/500x500/proj_05.png">
    <div id="newsTxt-136" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">06.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 8</font></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the 4-6 divs are displayed correctly and the last 3 are not. every time I load new tiles, the last batch is not diplayed correctly.

This behavior is linked to the oNewsMsnry.layout(). without this call all the AJAX appended are stacked at 0% and the same height.

Someone has any idea to fixe this issue ?

Thx a lot for all the help

PS : I've stayed with vanilla JS because the project has started like that and I have the habit of coding this way !

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just after posting the question I got and idea.

This behavior got me thinking that the problem was coming from the "unkown" dimension of the data at the moment the .layout() was called and that is why the next call, when the data is known, the display works. This is probably happening because we are here in a fit-to-size type of tiles configuration.

I've added an onloadeddata for video or onload for img event listeners to the last element of the batch to call a .layout() when the data transfer of the last element if finished :

```
<div class="grid-item" style="position: absolute; left: 66.3776%; top: 1952px;">
  <img src="./Images/News/139/500x500/photo_youtube.jpg" onload="msryLayout();">
  <div id="newsTxt-139" class="newsTxt" onclick="showDetails(this);"><font style="font-size:1.5em;"><font style="font-family:Euclide_Square_Bold;">03.08.2018 // CiLab</font> <br><br> super 11</font></div>
</div>
```

this way I got the layout to work when all the information needed for layout was available.